# rescue in check_for_missing_columns': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, yaml, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to run [this application](https://github.com/bikeindex/bike_index) via cloud9.io. I'm not a programmer. Tried everything I could comprehend, but hit a dead end. I try to run the app, but it throw an error. Here is the output:

```
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Auto-loading of `.env.development` will be removed in 1.0. See https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv-deployment if you would like to continue using this feature.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.22 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/doorkeeper-2.0.1/lib/doorkeeper/config.rb:29:in `rescue in check_for_missing_columns': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/doorkeeper-2.0.1/lib/doorkeeper/config.rb:21:in `check_for_missing_columns'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/doorkeeper-2.0.1/lib/doorkeeper/config.rb:11:in `configure'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:17:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'


Process exited with code: 1
[K

Process exited with code: 1
```

Here's the contents of database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: bikereg
  username: postgres
  password: !q2w3e4r5t
  pool: 5

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: bikereg_test

staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: bikereg_staging

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: bikereg_production
  pool: 25
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: have you run `rake db:setup`? did you run through all the steps in the [instructions](https://github.com/bikeindex/bike_index#running-the-bike-index-locally)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
No, I couldn't finish the instructions. Postgresql wasn't running, so I've started it. Now the output is:
http://pastebin.com/gBcxGaax

Comment: I see that permission denied to create database. But why? The Cloud9 manual said that DB should be pre-provisioned. Should the app use the DB that is stated in the yml?

Comment: It might help to post this in https://community.c9.io for more specific Cloud9 help

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545746/cloud9-postgres

Comment: @omouse thanks a lot. Will try tomorrow.