# postgresql error in Cloud9 "fe_sendauth: no password supplied"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I'd like to setup postgresql for my rails app in **Cloud9**.

Although I followed [the top voted answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545746/cloud9-postgres), the following error appeared when I tried to `bundle exec rake db:create`.

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
...
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "username"=>nil, "password"=>nil, "host"=>"0.0.0.0", "database"=>"app_development"}
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
...
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "username"=>nil, "password"=>nil, "host"=>"0.0.0.0", "database"=>"app_test"}
```

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
  host:     <%= ENV['IP'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.2'
```

Although I found similar questions in stackoverflow, they doesn't work for me.

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to avoid this error.

`Cloud 9` can't allow us to access to the `pg_hba.conf` file as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329650/fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied-error-after-setting-up-postgresql-database-on) mentioned.

**EDIT!!!**

`host:     localhost` was added instead of `host:     <%= ENV['IP'] %> in "database.yml"`

`sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             xxx                                     peer
```

instead of

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             username                                     peer
```

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` as a host refers to a TCP connection

so in your database.yml

```
host:     localhost
```

and you use same `username` and `password` for all three environment check this as well.

or `ENV['IP']` should be refer to `localhost`

check your auth method in `pg_hba.conf` it should be `md5`

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

and if

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             username                                  peer
```

then  you'd need to connect through Unix domain sockets

if you are using a debian-like OS, that means putting `/var/run/postgresql` in the host field

so in database.yml

```
 host:  "/var/run/postgresql"
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, @Rajarshi Das. `Cloud 9` can't allow us to access to the `pg_hba.conf` file as [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329650/fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied-error-after-setting-up-postgresql-database-on) mentioned. It would be appreciated if you could give me any idea.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue Cloud9 does not restrict access to that file, that's Linux doing it. You can edit it with `sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Brady Dowling. I can eidt `conf` file as you advised. But the same error is still displayed.

Comment: did you check your username password and host at database.yml ? should not be same for all three environments

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Rajarshi Das. Although I changed username, password and host at database.yml, the following error appeared. `could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: Not sure if I can help much more here but if you think this is related to Cloud9 you might find help by posting a topic at https://community.c9.io

Comment: Please add port in database.yml which is accuaring by your database postgresql