# Best way to set up a postgres database in a Rails app in Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cloud9-ide

I want to know what is the best to set up postgres in c9 in order to deploy to heroku.

I follow this https://www.codecademy.com/articles/deploy-rails-to-heroku it worked on a test app but it didn't push the code to heroku on the main app!

I am really afraid that by working around with the database, I would mess up the app.

Please help and thanks in advance!

Edit!!

I followed the first answer of this post [Cloud9 postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545746/cloud9-postgres) and i got the error.

here my `gem file`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assetsbu
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.8'
gem 'css_convertor', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: There is no "best way". Rather you should state how you have attempted setting up a postgres db in c9 and if you encountered any errors.

Comment: In fact, i did!

Comment: here it is: `PG::ConnectionBad
fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Extracted source (around line #651):
649
650
651
652
653
654
              
        # connected server's characteristics.
        def connect
          @connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters)

          # Money type has a fixed precision of 10 in PostgreSQL 8.2 and below, and as of
          # PostgreSQL 8.3 it has a fixed precision of 19. PostgreSQLColumn.extract_precision`

Comment: When did you receive that error? Also post your gemfile.

Comment: I edited the question, please check it out

Comment: I still dont see at what point are you encountering the error. Is it when you are trying to run bundle install? Also you need rails_12factor gem for deployment to heroku.

Comment: I encouter the probelm whenever I try rails s. I already deployed the app to heroku without rails_12factor gem

Comment: I strongly suggest reading up on what the rails_12factor gem does and why you need it. Or else you will face problems with your app on heroku in the future. For now you are unable to boot your rails server in development because your setup is wrong. As indicated from the error it says "no password supplied"

Comment: You are correct! and I will add the gem and push to heroku as soon as I can, Thanks

Comment: It is just that I cant boot rails server in development

Comment: As mentioned, your setup for the postgres db is wrong

Comment: How to correct it?

Comment: As you might guess, i am fairly new to rails

Comment: I can't tell you whats wrong or how to correct it if i dont see your code

Comment: sounds goods. here my git https://github.com/Hekmataref/MyStartup. Please check it out!